# Modular programming in Cocoa - help keeping references grouped together

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, architecture, delegates

I have a network part, some business logic, and view classes logically separated in groups. I want to arrange them in a modular style such that the networking part can later be replaced with another networking module. I'm no expert in these concepts (encapsulation, etc.), so currently I try to keep references to related classes inside a group and never reference them outside this group.

The project runs on Cocoa. The networking part use Bonjour and will publish a service (self) and browse for similar services. The resulting array will have to be sent to a table view so that users can select the desired service to connect to. Currently this is accomplished with delegation.

My class hierarchy, networking group:

```
NetController        // Entrance to the networking group
Socket               // Create a socket for service (self)
Bonjour              // Bonjour manager
  BonjourPublish     // Publish a service on the network
  BonjourBrowse      // Browse for other services on the network
```

The problem is that for the delegation to work, I have to set the reference of the class that will do the delegation in the view that receive the array of services:

```
[[[netController bonjour] serviceBrowser] setDelegate:self];
```

I want the NetController class to be the entrance point for the networking class group, but this call is going much deeper into the hierarchy. The benefit of delegation is that it allows loose coupling between classes, but I must admit I don't see the effect of this benefit.

1. What's the best practice for dealing with these types of problems?
2. Generally I need some good resources on modular programming. I find these concepts very interesting and relevant. Does anyone have recommendations on books or web resources related to this.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try a protocol:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Protocols

and implement some factory interface which can create and return objects conforming to the protocol, but is specialized for the task/implementation required.

so, you can create your own protocols. hypothetical illustration of a problem set and interfaces:

```
@protocol MONNetworkDataProvider;

@class MONNetworkLocation;
@class MONNetworkConnectionType;

@protocol MONNetworkConnection /* among other services, this may be your Bonjour manager */

- (MONNetworkConnectionType *)networkConnectionType;

- (BOOL)isServiceAvailable;
- (BOOL)isConnected;

- (MONNetworkErrorCode)connect:(NSError**)outError;

- (NSData *)helpMeGetTheDataAThisLocation:(MONNetworkLocation *)location error:(NSError**)outError;

@end

/* this is usually used in some controller, and can be used to parse or process the results it's interested in */
@protocol MONNetworkDataRecipient

- (NSArray *)typesOfInterest; /* called by MONNetworkDataProvider. used to minimize data returned and requests */

/* MONNetworkDataProvider callbacks: */
- (void)networkRequestFailed:(NSObject<MONNetworkDataProvider>*)provider withError:(NSError *)error;
- (void)networkRequestSucceeded:(NSObject<MONNetworkDataProvider>*)provider data:(NSData *)data;

/* the remainder is useful for the controller: */
- (BOOL)hasRequestCompleted;
- (BOOL)didRequestSucceed;
- (NSError *)errorFromRequest;

/* assuming all went well: */
- (NSArray *)decodedResults;

@end

@protocol MONNetworkDataProvider /* mediates betweeen the connection and recipient. also handles threading */

- (id)initWithLocation:(MONNetworkLocation *)location recipient:(NSObject<MONNetworkDataRecipient>*)inRecipient connection:(NSObject<MONNetworkConnection>*)inConnection;

- (NSObject<MONNetworkConnection>*)connection;
- (NSObject<MONNetworkDataRecipient>*)recipient;

/* informs self.recipient when the read is complete */
- (void)readAsynchronously;

/* informs self.recipient when the read is complete */
- (void)readSynchronously;

@end

/*
    now the factory MONNetworkingFactory only needs to know about all the variants of MONNetworkConnection and MONNetworkDataProvider needed for this app.
    it creates and returns something appropriate, given the context of the arguments, day of the week, whatever else you like.
*/
@interface MONNetworkingFactory : NSObject

+ (NSObject<MONNetworkConnection>*)newMONNetworkConnectionForService(NSString * service);

+ (NSObject<MONNetworkDataProvider>*)newMONNetworkDataProviderForLocation:(MONNetworkLocation *)location recipient:(NSObject<MONNetworkDataRecipient>*)inRecipient connection:(NSObject<MONNetworkConnection>*)inConnection;

@end
```

then you implement these as needed, for the variant types/implementations which offer these services. when a request is made, the factory returns something appropriate given the arguments. the protocols may declare all the 'interface' you need in your app, and may be divided as you see is appropriate. each implementation can encapsulate the types and implementation they use. therefore, the data recipient doesn't need to see the interface of any (provided it's all in the protocol, of course).

Comment: In BonjourBrowse, I already have defined the protocol BonjourBrowseDelegate with a delegate method willUpdateList:(NSMutableArray *)services. This is fired in the viewController when browsing for services are completed. Not sure if I understand what you mean here, can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @sandvikc depends on the abstractions you want. updated/expanded

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for so now I have some reading to do :) This concept is new to me, but I found a design pattern called Abstract Factory and I guess that's what you refer to. Thanks, this is really helpful!

Comment: @sandvikc you're welcome. `MONNetworkingFactory`, as presented in the example could technically be used as multiple factory patterns, although yes Abstract Factory is what the interface really suggests (objc's just a very dynamic lang). another very common form is the Factory Method. an example of this would be implemented as a new instance method of the protocol MONNetworkConnection: `-(MONNetworkDataProvider *)newNetworkDataProviderWithLocation:recipient:`. so there are technically multiple subtypes of factories. which is best depends on your implementation needs/design. good luck!